# How can I make a snapshot of the surface using SKSurface.Snapshot()?

Tags: android, xamarin, canvas, snapshot, skiasharp

The following code breaks the code, and my App closes when I click the Button.

I tried to take a snapshot inside the method, but it crashes the App.

```
SKSurface CenterSurface;
void canvasView_BubbleCenterCircle(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
{
    var surface = e.Surface;
    var canvas = surface.Canvas;

    canvas.Clear(SKColors.Black);

    var width = e.Info.Width;
    var height = e.Info.Height;

    // Move the origin to the center
    canvas.Translate(width / 2, height / 2);

    canvas.DrawLine(-220, 0, 220, 0, whitePaint);
    canvas.DrawLine(0, -220, 0, 220, whitePaint);
        
    // Draw base graphics
    canvas.DrawCircle(0, 0, 180f, whitePaint);

    canvas.DrawCircle(x, y, 50f, whitePaint);
    canvas.DrawLine(x, y, x, y + 35, whitePaint);
    canvas.DrawLine(x, y - 35, x, y, whitePaint);
    canvas.DrawLine(x, y, x + 35, y, whitePaint);
    canvas.DrawLine(x - 35, y, x, y, whitePaint);

    CenterSurface = surface;       
}


private async void cameraButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FinalCenterImage = CenterSurface.Snapshot();
    //...
}
```

Comment: you need to determine what exception causes the crash.  Add some exception handling

Comment: I added, but is skips the exception.
try { FinalCenterImage = CenterSurface.Snapshot(); }
catch (Exception ex) { Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message); }

Comment: Are there any exception messages?

Comment: I found the problem, I called the snapshot() method 60 times per second, and the cpu couldn't handle it, I changed it to one per second and my app didn't crash anymore, Thanks for the answers.